# build failed: while using ant

Tags: android

I am getting following error while building the project with ANT INSTALL command

---

BUILD FAILED

Target "INSTALL" does not exist in the project "debug".

---

Please inform if anything else is needed...

Thanks

here is the build.xml:

/*

[This is typically used for code obfuscation.
     Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
     If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}]
    
    
-->

```
<!-- Execute the Android Setup task that will setup some properties
     specific to the target, and import the build rules files.

     The rules file is imported from
        <SDK>/platforms/<target_platform>/ant/ant_rules_r#.xml

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <setup> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole script.
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, *after* the <setup> task
         - disable the import of the rules by changing the setup task
           below to <setup import="false" />. 
         - customize to your needs.
-->
<setup />
```

*/

Comment: Post your build.xml or a portion of it in order to get some help.

Comment: Are you trying to build lib project?

Answer (score 0):

please try lowercase:

```
ant install
```